Gradle Error while running flutter project in Android Studio java
I am completely new to flutter. Yesterday I installed flutter, added path variables and it works straight from cmd. I also created a project using cmd and opened it in Android Studio. Import of Dart and Flutter plugins has done, too.
Then what the problem could be here ?
enter image description here
Resolution

You need to update your question with details of your gradle setup: used versions, build.gradle files. usually this happens because too old Kotlin Gradle plugin used with too recent Android Gradle Plugin and/or gradle itself. But it is impossible to say now without info about your environment

1.The error messages mention problems with the root project 'android' and project 'app'. This could show a Gradle configuration issue. Try the following:
Open the android directory in your project and check if the build.gradle file is present.
Make sure the build.gradle file is correctly configured. You can try to sync the Gradle files by clicking on the Sync Now button in the top-right corner of the Android Studio window.
2.Make sure that the android directory is correctly configured as a module in the project structure. You can do this by going to File > Project Structure and checking the Modules section.
Ensure that the app directory is correctly configured.
If none of these suggestions help, please provide more details about your project, such as:
The output of the 'flutter doctor' command
Any other error messages you're seeing
